# Azure Logic Apps xpath not returning value

Tags: xml, xpath, azure-logic-apps

I am working on a logic app which calls a SOAP API. I'm trying to extract the value of a node from the XML response but can't seem to get a value output that I can then use in further actions.

This is an abridged version of the XML response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Body>
        <DoLoginResponse xmlns="http://apiserver.wireless.com/0905/">
            <DoLoginResult>
                <OperationStatus>true</OperationStatus>
                <StatusMessage />
                <SecurityProfile>
                    <User>
                        <UserID>6e37c720-b40e-4a4b-8e7a-b0c431ac8749</UserID>
                    </User>
                    <Session>
                        <SessionId>888c9c94-f33b-4766-97c0-8f8031bda104</SessionId>
                    </Session>
                </SecurityProfile>
                <Authenticated>true</Authenticated>
            </DoLoginResult>
        </DoLoginResponse>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

In the Logic Apps designer I am wanting to extract the **Authenticated** and **SessionID** nodes.  For example, I attempt to get the Authenticated node value by using the xpath function:

```
xpath(outputs('xml'),'/Envelope/Body/DoLoginResponse/DoLoginResult/Authenticated')
```

After running, the output is `[]`

As a newbie to working with XML, any help is appreciated argh.

Comment: I was able to use the following function successfully:
`xpath(outputs('xml'),'/*[local-name() = "Envelope"]/*[local-name() = "Body"]/*[local-name() = "DoLoginResponse"]/*[local-name() = "DoLoginResult"]/*[local-name() = "Authenticated"]/text()')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the document element is not `Envelope`, it is `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Envelope` which would be able to use the shorthand `soap:Envelope` if you were able to pass a NamespaceManager in Logic Apps, which you can't. Yes, XPath is that pedantic. Namespace matters in XPath.

To make this somewhat simpler, you can use the syntax `/*[local-name() = 'Envelope']`, which disregards the element's namespace. Or, given that you expect to query inside a SOAP message whose structure is known, abbreviate this further to `/*`, since you know the document element will always be `soap:Envelope`.

Logic Apps are **bad** at manipulating XML, and given a choice, I'd use Functions or indeed almost anything else.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that - I had a notion it had something to do with the namespace not being recognised in Logic Apps properly.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the Azure Logic Apps designer, but the problem with the XPath expression is the namespace of the DoLoginResponse node.  There are a few ways to deal with this, but if you really just want to ignore the namespace you can use an expression like:

```
/Envelope/Body/*[local-name() = "DoLoginResponse"]/*[local-name() = "DoLoginResult"]/*[local-name() = "Authenticated"]/string()
```

Body/* selects all of the child nodes of Body.  The predicate (local-name() = 'DoLoginResponse') restricts that sequence to only those with a local node name of 'DoLoginResponse'.  And so on.

If you want to check for the namespace too, you can expand the predicates like:

```
[local-name() = "DoLoginResponse" and namespace-uri() = "http://apiserver.wireless.com/0905/"]
```

Lastly, you may be trying to extract the atomic value of Authenticated instead of the entire Authenticated node.  For example, if you just want to select the content of Authenticated as text/string, you can do:

```
/Envelope/Body/*[local-name() = 'DoLoginResponse']/*[local-name() = 'DoLoginResult']/*[local-name() = 'Authenticated']/text()
```

Since I am not familiar with the API you are using, you may need to be careful with the quotation marks in my examples here.  Not sure if they need to be escaped.

Comment: Does XPath respect the document's default namespace, such that `Envelope` matches what you'd reasonably expect it to? I've never noticed this, but that's a slight improvement on the behaviour I've seen previously, which is to expect every name to be namespace-qualified.

Comment: I believe it's specifically the default namespace that is the challenge here.  Yes, you can use similar techniques for Envelope but because it is unambiguous I believe XPath allows you to omit it.  I see explanations to the effect of "A prefix must be bound to prevent ambiguity when querying documents with some nodes not in a namespace, and some in a default namespace."  The local-name() approach circumvents this requirement.